# What is a Folmer Graflex gravity-type synchronizer?

Tags: flash, film

What is a Folmer Graflex gravity-type synchronizer? What is it used for? I bought one because it was in a nice wooden box. I found none on eBay and no information anywhere else.

Comment: Can you take and add a photograph of the device, for illustration?

Answer (score 4):

It tests shutter sync speeds.

http://www.radionerds.com/images/c/c3/TM_11-2378_1944.pdf    page numbered 1

I doubt it has much use today.

Comment: OK. At least I know what it is now. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the user manual for one: http://www.cameramanuals.org/prof_pdf/graflex_flash_synchronizer.pdf

Comment: OK. At least I know what it is now. Thanks for the link